# Cannot start activity via explicit intent while using Koin (Koincontext already started)

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I have two activities: a MainActivity and LoginActivity.
MainActivity contains a fragment with an account sign out option, then opens an intent to show LoginActivity.

I am using Koin as DI. I am getting this error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{***/***.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A KoinContext is already started`

For the following code:

```
    private fun setListeners(){
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener {
        firebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
        activity?.finish()
        val intent = Intent(context, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity((intent))
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Should I inject LoginActivity via Koin? Should intents not be used with Koin?

Comment: The activity launch code is not that important in this case.
attach the place you initialize Koin and how you inject your dependencies into your activities.
Strip down the problem with even empty modules that don't inject implementations and mock every dependency with empty implementation.
My guess? even with empty modules you will get the crash since you are initializing Koin in my then one place in you App.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private fun setListeners(){
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener {
        firebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
        activity?.finish()
        val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity((intent))
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. It doesn't recognize fragment as a context for "this" purposes

Comment: try adding `this@LoginActivity`

Comment: And to answer if Kotlin shouldnt be used. I use intents in my projects everytime i need to start a new activity.